# Open2 Api failure while installing Mead software

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am running into some issues trying to install a software called MEAD . I would appreciate if someone could have alook .

I get the following error while installing

/mead/bin # ./mead.pl GA3

Using system rc-file: /home/karosh/mead/bin/../.meadrc

Warning: Can't find user rc-file
Cluster: /home/karosh/mead/bin/../data/GA3/GA3.cluster

open2: exec of /home/karosh/mead/bin/driver.pl failed at ./mead.pl line 230

THe mead software is not written by me so I have not changed any of the perl scrips . I line 230 in the driver.pl file is

```
sub run_mead {

    my %options = @_;

    my $reader = FileHandle->new();
    my $writer = FileHandle->new();

    unless ( open2($reader, $writer, "$FindBin::Bin/driver.pl") ) {
        die "Unable to run MEAD.\n";
    }
...
...

}
```

Does this error mean that open2 was not found . The mead folks have put the following line in the file:

```
use strict;

use File::Spec;

use FileHandle; 

use IPC::Open2;
```

Or does it mean that i need to install the rpm that contains the API . I see that this API is a part of the core perl bundle http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open2.html. So why was it not installed ? Do i need to install perl again .

Someone has earlier faced this problem - http://www.summarization.com/~radev/mead/email/0160.html  but the solution is not working for me . I find no Perl files with the incorrect perl directives . The mead team has been dissolved and there is no one to ask questions but I need to use this software.

I think if some one can explain me the meaning of the error than I can do deeper. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means that `.../driver.pl` doesn't have execute permission. Change the file permissions or call it like

```
open2($reader, $writer, "perl $FindBin::Bin/driver.pl")
open2($reader, $writer, "$^X $FindBin::Bin/driver.pl")
```

Comment: thanks @mob . it was indeed the permission problem . Thanks aton !